# Why did monaco-editor getValue() return an unexpected length

Tags: javascript, typescript, editor, monaco-editor

Here I use editor.setValue() to render a string to the editor, the result in the render view was correct

But when I use editor.getValue() again, and print the result string length, I got an unexpected result.

Here is the code.

```
var value = `asfdasfsa\n\nasdfasdfasdfal;k l;'k \r\n \r\n  \r\n   k 'a\r\n  skd \r\n   a\r\n   d \r\n    \r\n     sas\r\n      dffa\r\n       sd\r\n         fsd\r\n          f\r\n          sfasfdasfasfdasdffasfaf\n\n          fa ljjflkajl\n\n          false\n\n\r\n\n          A\r\n          jpakfafafafaffaffaffafafewfwe\n          `;

console.log(value.length); // 280
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: value,
    language: 'javascript',

    lineNumbers: 'off',
    roundedSelection: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    readOnly: false,
    theme: 'vs-dark'
});

console.log(editor.getValue().length) // 290
```

This question has been bothering me for a long time, and I still haven't found the answer

Can somebody help answer this question ah, thank you very much~~

Comment: There's nothing obvious which would explain this behavior, so try with a simple short string what happens. Once you got to a value that returns the expected length go further, and more chars, add control chars (like tab + line break) and check again, until you find at least where things start to get wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the difference between 280 and 290 is because Monaco is adding `\r`  before any `\n` in your string that doesn't have a `\r` already (so it's effectively normalising all end of line characters in the string). If you change your last `console.log` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(editor.getValue()), editor.getValue().length)` you will see how the value has changed and some additional `\r`'s have been added.

[This comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/559#issuecomment-342539893) suggests that Monaco takes the input string and splits it into lines (looking for `\r\n` or `\r` or `\n`). The value of `editor.getValue()` will return the individual lines, joined by the same line separator that was used when the editor was created, hence a different character count when compared to the input string.

If you paste the following code into the [Monaco Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html), you will see that it adds additional `\r`'s and therefore the string returned from the editor (`editor.getValue()`) is 2 characters longer than the value supplied (`value`):

```
var value = `'line 1'\n\'line 2'\r\r\n'line 3'`;

console.log(JSON.stringify(value), value.length); // "'line 1'\n'line 2'\r\r\n'line 3'" 28
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: value,
    language: 'javascript',

    lineNumbers: 'off',
    roundedSelection: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    readOnly: false,
    theme: 'vs-dark'
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(editor.getValue()), editor.getValue().length) // "'line 1'\r\n'line 2'\r\n\r\n'line 3'" 30
```